# What is it called when I create an object where it's entries are variables?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, terminology

For example

```
let firstName = 'James';
let lastName = 'Brown';

let person = { firstName, lastName }

// which creates a person object that looks like
{ firstName: 'James', lastName: 'Brown' }
```

My question is what is what I'm doing here called?

Comment: [Short-hand notation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon - thank you! I was suggesting to someone to do this and realized I had no idea what it's called.